# Pseudo Code in jGrasp

Tags: pseudocode, jgrasp

While writing pseudo code for java in jGrasp, do we write it in a comment or do we write it like any other code? I have already read the wiki page but wasn't able to reach a satisfactory understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the pseudo code is basically a very detailed version of your code, you don't need to write it like any other code, you can write it as comments (these comments should let you or the person reading know what they would have to type in the program). In grade 12 computer science when we are told to write the pseudo code we just type it in words describing what is going to process, what does my code do basically do etc. I am really not sure how higher level coders do their pseudo code but as far as I know you can write it in a comment. ( you can/should type your pseudo code in word ) . I hope this helped.